# Assert two json content by ignoring the order in cucumber

Tags: ruby, json, cucumber

I am comparing two json content or objects in ruby+cucumber like this
but when i compare, it does not ignores the order of content if it varies. I know this statement compares as two strings. So is there anyway i can compare two json objects by ignoring its order sequence?

```
expect(@act_resp_excl_key).to eq(exp_data_excl_key)
```

Adding little more information with above details. i have two json document like below.

```
json1 = {
    "entries" =  > [{
                "doingBusinessAsName" =  > "KROGER FOODS",
                "legalName" =  > "Kroger-Corps"
            }
        ]
}

json2 = {
    "entries" =  > [{
                "legalName" =  > "Kroger-Corps"
                "doingBusinessAsName" =  > "KROGER FOODS",
            }
        ]
}
```

When i compare these two json in ruby+cucumber, i get the result as failure. But logically it is same and i should get pass. I use the above comparison statement to validate two jsons.

@tgf,
I used the statement which you specified, but still my comparison fails. could you please help me what could be the issue?

```
expect(JSON.parse(@act_resp_excl_key)).to eq JSON.parse(exp_data_excl_key)
```

Comment: Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read your question, only pretend you're being asked the question. Does it tell you enough to understand the problem? Does it give you data to use to test the code? We can't help you unless you give us minimal sample data and minimal code demonstrating the problem, and your expected output. We can cobble up sample test code and data but that's your responsibility; Help us help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the data is simply JSON in a string (please post example of data) you can just parse it to a ruby hash and compare that.

```
require 'json'
JSON.parse(@act_resp_excl_key).class => Hash
```

Then assert the two hashes are equal:

```
expect(JSON.parse(@act_resp_excl_key)).to eq JSON.parse(exp_data_excl_key)
```

This works even if the order is different.

Comment: I used the statement "expect(JSON.parse(@act_resp_excl_key)).to eq JSON.parse(exp_data_excl_key)" which you specified, but still my comparison fails. could you please help me what could be the issue?

Comment: Yes now i am able to see the proper comparison. Thanks for your solution. FYI...Json inputs which i gave is typo error. the comma should come next to "legalName" tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your commas are not in the correct locations for json2.

```
> json1 = { "entries" => [{ "doingBusinessAsName" => "KROGER FOODS", "legalName" => "Kroger-Corps" } ] }
=> {"entries"=>[{"doingBusinessAsName"=>"KROGER FOODS", "legalName"=>"Kroger-Corps"}]}
> json2 = { "entries" => [{ "legalName" => "Kroger-Corps", "doingBusinessAsName" => "KROGER FOODS" } ] }
=> {"entries"=>[{"legalName"=>"Kroger-Corps", "doingBusinessAsName"=>"KROGER FOODS"}]}
> json1==json2
=> true
```

Comment: Thanking in stack overflow is an uptick.